# How does it work?

Tags: c++, loops, iterator, set

When I am using "it" before for_each, I get 
11
7
15
and second loop 
-10 
-3
and so on

```
int main()
{
    std::set<int> mySet;

    mySet.insert(5);
    mySet.insert(3);
    mySet.insert(1);
    mySet.insert(-10);
    mySet.insert(11); // <-
    mySet.insert(15);
    mySet.insert(-3);
    mySet.insert(4);
    mySet.insert(7);
    mySet.insert(1);

    std::set<int>::iterator it = mySet.find(11);
    mySet.erase(11);

    for(; it != mySet.end(); it++)
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;

    for(auto &temp : mySet)
        std::cout << temp << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

but, when I am using "it" after for_each, I get
-10 -3...15 and next (some number, in my case 48, i guess it's just trash) 7 15 
I just decided try it, and to look what will happens
and now I understood, that I nothing understood)))
for_each loop doesn't matter, instead would be any operation
and sorry for my English

Comment: Could you have come up with a question title more vague than that?

Answer (score 3):

You have undefined behavior in your code. After you erase element with key `11`, an iterator pointing to it is no longer valid, and it's usage in the following loop is illegal.

Because of that, whatever results you get in your program are irrelevant.

Comment: Correct answer, but maybe could have been improved by posting a link and pointing out that it=mySet.erase(it) would have fixed the code http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase